# Nutch, NoSuchElementException error after removing table from Hbase

Tags: hbase, nutch, nosuchelementexception

I use nutch for crawling some sites. One time i decide to clear all crawling result and just remove "webpage" table from Hbase store, using hbase shell.

After that nutch trow exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.TreeMap.key(TreeMap.java:1221)
at java.util.TreeMap.firstKey(TreeMap.java:285)
at org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore.execute(MemStore.java:125)
at org.apache.gora.query.impl.QueryBase.execute(QueryBase.java:73)
at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.executeQuery(GoraRecordReader.java:68)
at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.nextKeyValue(GoraRecordReader.java:110)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

"inject" task work without error, but everything else just throw the error (generate, fetch, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my config files, i just mixed content nutch-site.xml and hbase-
site.xml

But it's very strange, so big mistake and nothing in log.